# creating a ":" delimited list in bash script using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have following lines

```
380:<CHECKSUM_VALIDATION>
393:</CHECKSUM_VALIDATION>
437:<CHECKSUM_VALIDATION>
441:</CHECKSUM_VALIDATION>
```

I need to format it as below

```
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:380:393
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:437:441
```

Is it possible to achieve above output using "awk"? [I'm using bash]

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk -F '[:<>/]+' '{ n = $1; getline; print $2 ":" n ":" $1 }'
```

Explanation:

- Set the field separator with `-F` to be a sequence of a mix of `:<>/` characters, this way the first field will be the number, and the second will be `CHECKSUM_VALIDATION`
- Save the first field in variable `n` and read the next line (which would overwrite `$1`)
- Print the line: a combination of the number from the previous line, and the fields on the current line

Another approach without using `getline`:

```
awk -F '[:<>/]+' 'NR % 2 { n = $1 } NR % 2 == 0 { print $2 ":" n ":" $1 }'
```

This one uses the record counter `NR` to determine whether it's time to print: if `NR` is odd, save the first field in `n`, if `NR` is even, then print.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 'N; s/\([0-9]\+\):<\(.*\)>\n\([0-9]\+\):<\(.*\)>/\2:\1:\3/' file.txt
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~$ sed 'N; s/\([0-9]\+\):<\(.*\)>\n\([0-9]\+\):<\(.*\)>/\2:\1:\3/' file.txt
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:380:393
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:437:441
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
awk -F: '/<C/ {printf "CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:%d:",$1; next} {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `gnu awk`

```
awk -F"[:\n<>]" 'NR==1{print $3,$1,$5;f=$3;next} $3{print f,$3,$7}' OFS=":" RS="</CH" file
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:380:393
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:437:441
```

Based on Jonas post and avoiding `getline`, this `awk` should do:

```
awk -F '[:<>/]+' '/<C/ {f=$1;next} { print $2,f,$1}' OFS=\: file
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:380:393
CHECKSUM_VALIDATION:437:441
```